How to trigger adhoc tasks on BPMN projects
I have created the below diagram on a BPMN modeler.

The objective of this diagram is to complete user tasks and after all done,
the process should Invoice all jobs based on a Script that will run on "L" event.
I would like to have my process do the following example :
User completes tasks from "A" to "C" , then Subprocess "D" begins and he needs
to select which jobs are needed to be worked in parallel (it can be only "A" or all of them "A", "B", "C", "D").
Everytime that some of the above is completed that Job should be send via Script task onto "L" in order to Invoice the job done. Same thing will happen to next Subprocesses ("G", "H", "I", "J") , user will select from "F" and then do the same thing.
A request that came in was that process needs to have the ability to go back on the process and trigger something to Open again.
For example , suppose user completed everything (he selected from "D" subprocess only "A" & "B") and he is now on user task "K" but he forgot that he wanted to add on the process also task "C" from subprocess "D" but does not need to go through other steps again.
How can this be achieved?

I think this kind of flexibility shows that you are not describing a process. Rather you are describing knowledge work. The knowledge worker decides what needs to be done. To support this a case management tool could be used. There is the Case Management Model and Notation specification (CMMN). Some BPMN tools even support it.
